# The design section in WindowBuilder goes blank when parsing one specific JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, windowbuilder

I have implemented new code into my Java Swing project when suddenly one single panel goes blank on the design tab. Is there any known type of implementation that may interfere this way?

[Blank design tab with one panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETssg.png)

[Normal design tab with any other panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eklj6.png)

I wish I could share the whole code, but since its GUI oriented it gets pretty long.

I am currently trying to locate the problem by mixing the current code with the last commit pretty much randomly. I would really appreciate it if you shared better ideas for locating the source of the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: WindowBuilder detects code patterns instead of saving the layout in a separate file like other GUI builders do. This way, the Java code can directly be edited as long as no unknown code pattern is used. So look in particular at the way in which elements are created or specified. You might start with a minimal working example and then apply the newly used code patterns one after the other to create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. I was using **my own custom components** and at some point decided to **modify the behaviour** of my extension table based on **external parameters**:

```
private CustomTable getTable() {
    if (table == null) {

        table = new CustomTable(frame.getService().getRegistros(), booleanField);
        
        ...
```

To fix this

```
private CustomTable getTable() {
if (table == null) {

    table = new CustomTable(frame.getService().getRegistros());

    ...
```

So apparently WindowBuilder struggles when it comes to the rendering of heavily modified components even if they are separate from the main GUI panel.

Thanks for the comments! :)